# Is the body of this document not allowing the nav bar to align to the left?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I've built this in many different ways, and each time I've wanted to get the nav bar on the left side of the page. Each time, I try to do it differently, but I know I'm missing something. Please help.  I build the body, and then I hope to float the navigation along the left of the body.

What am I not getting?? Thank you.
Code below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

main,
nav {
  display: block;
}

#container {
  width: 760px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  width: 850px;
  height: 1200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: lightgreen
}

h1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#paraFirst {
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
}

#listSomething {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
}

.orderedList {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
}

#rest {
  width: 400px;
  height: 780px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 315px;
  bottom: 155px;
}

nav {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 70px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <main id="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Pixel Art</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="paraFirst">
      <p>Pixel art is a form of digital art, created through the use of software, where images are edited on the pixel level. The aesthetic for this kind of graphics comes from 8-bit and 16-bit computers and video game consoles, in addition to other limited
        systems such as graphing calculators. In most pixel art, the color palette used is extremely limited in size, with some pixel art using only two colors. Creating or modifying pixel art characters or objects for video games is sometimes called
        spriting, a term that arose from the hobbyist community. The term likely came from the term sprite, a term used in computer graphics to describe a two-dimensional bitmap that is used in tandem with other bitmaps to construct a larger scene.</p>
    </div>


    <div id="listSomething">
      <h5>Somethings just gotta be listed . . . .</h5>
      <ol>
        <li class="orderedList">Cool Pixel Art</li>
        <li class="orderedList">Eh Pixel Art</li>
        <li class="orderedList">Dodo pixel art</li>
      </ol>
    </div>


    <div id="rest">
      <h3>History</h3>


      <p>The earliest counterparts of modern pixel art could be found in the electronic advertising displays of New York City during the early 20th century, with simple monochromatic light bulb matrix displays extant circa 1937.[1] Pixel art as it is known
        today largely originates from classic video games, particularly classic arcade games such as Space Invaders (1978) and Pac-Man (1980), and 8-bit consoles such as the Nintendo Entertainment System (1983) and Sega Master System (1985). The term
        pixel art was first published by Adele Goldberg and Robert Flegal of Xerox Palo Alto Research Center in 1982.[2] The concept, however, goes back about 11 years before that, for example in Richard Shoup's SuperPaint system in 1972, also at Xerox
        PARC.[3] Some traditional art forms, such as counted-thread embroidery (including cross-stitch) and some kinds of mosaic and beadwork, are very similar to pixel art. These art forms construct pictures out of small colored units similar to the
        pixels of modern digital computing. A similar concept on a much bigger scale can be seen in the North Korean Arirang Festival.</p>



      <h4>Definition</h4>


      <p>Although the definition of the medium is not concrete, the majority of pixel artists agree that an image can be categorized as pixel art when the artist is manipulating the image with deliberate control over the placement of each individual pixel.[4]
        When purposefully editing in this way, changing the position of a few pixels can have a drastic effect on the image. Most pixel artists do not consider images that have had filters applied to them which cause the image to look pixellated to be
        the same as pixel art, as the pixels that make up the image were not consciously placed by the artist, and usually do not hold much importance to the bigger picture. A common characteristic in pixel art is the low overall colour count in the image.
        Pixel art as a medium mimics a lot of traits found in older video game graphics, rendered by machines which were capable of only outputting a limited number of colours at once. Additionally, many pixel artists are of the opinion that in most cases,
        using a large number of colours, especially when very similar to each other in value, is unnecessary, and detracts from the overall cleanliness of the image, making it look messier. Many experienced pixel artists recommend not using more colours
        than necessary.</p>
    </div>

  </main>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Slidell</li>
      <li>ATL</li>
      <li>Family</li>
      <li>About Me</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your nav above main? Also, it doesn't make sense to have float left and then margin-left/margin-right auto. Float will place your nav on the left, the margins will place the nav in the centre which means they are going to be overridden by your float style. Remove all of the three and move nav above main

Comment: +1 thank you. This worked. But I still hope to learn how to get it from the bottom of the HTML doc to the top left with CSS. I watch others do that just to show the float: left; works, but when I use it, doesn't work like theirs. I've been watching Stephan Mischook's videos.

Comment: Think of HTML as a skeleton, what you put on top comes on top and what you put below comes below. When you float left you are telling the element to float to the left of its container. Your code would need some adjustments to be more readable. If you build an entire website based on floats you will have a lot of issues. Investigate and read a bit more about html and css and you will eventually get it.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**
Move the nav section below above your `main` tag

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Slidell</li>
    <li>ATL</li>
    <li>Family</li>
    <li>About Me</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
.
.
.
```

**CSS**

It doesn't make sense to have float left and then margin-left/margin-right auto. Float will place your nav on the left, the margins will place the nav in the centre which means they are going to be overridden by your float style. You also don't need `position: relative` or  `left:0px`.

```
nav {
 width: 70px;
 height: 250px;
 border: 5px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```